# Iframe in PHP with string from SQL

Tags: php, regex, string, youtube

I'm trying to convert a YouTube video link to You Tube embed link. A string will receive the YouTube link from SQL, another code will convert to embed link and converted link will be used inside a iframe. I don't know why its not working.

YouTube converter code (I'm trying to use any of these: [Link to Embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050890/find-youtube-link-in-php-string-and-convert-it-into-embed-code))

```
function convertYoutube($string) {
    return preg_replace(
        "/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i",
        "<iframe src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$2\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
        $string
    );
}
```

String that receive YouTube link from SQL

```
$row["link"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute this, you will see the embeded youtube video. The `$object` is the embeded youtube url.

```
<?php 
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RboEKl7GgU0";
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $v );
$object = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$v['v'].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
echo $object;
?>
```

Instead of the `$url` you can obviously just use your `$row['link']`

Comment: @JoaoZanetti I have tested this code, and it works fine exactly like it above. It either has to do with the `URL` you are feeding it or something else. Please provide more information about how to `url` looks like if still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what is going wrong for you then, I have tried it with that link and any other, I get a great result.

Comment: In chrome its white, in Vivaldi its showing "This plugin is not supported."

Comment: I have updated my code, see if this is working better for you. I have tested this too, and it works just fine ( It looks a lot better as well ). @JoaoZanetti

Comment: @JoaoZanetti Please let me know if this has solved your problem!

Comment: Yeah, now its working, showing player, but not showing videol. https://gyazo.com/6aed8bab6f3f1010b432d393c54d8677

Comment: Then your `url` is simply the wrong one. If you copy paste my code in a simple `php` file and load that one, you get the result you want.

Comment: Yeah, look like the problem now is with my link, but your code is working! Thanks.

Comment: Happy to have helped!